# Unable to create huge file

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to create a file with 100.000.000 records using Python. No matter what method I choose, I always get memory_error.

I have tried multiprocessing.

```py
def mp_worker(number):
    number += 1
    return number

def mp_handler():
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    #numbers = list(range(1000000))
    with open('results.txt', 'w') as f:
        for result in p.imap(mp_worker, range(100000000)):
            line = generateCustomerData(result)
            f.write('%s\n' % line)
            f.flush()
```

Expected result is a file with 100.000.000 records.
The actual result is a memory_error.

Comment: What is your question? You are running out of memory. Get more memory!

Comment: did you try without multiprocessing, without threads, etc.? Maybe then it will run correctly because only one process will write in file  so it will not have to keep more then one record in memory.

Comment: Depending on the OS you're using, you may need to make sure the main module can be safely imported. See the section [The spawn and forkserver start methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods) in the `multiprocessing` [Programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines).